# Is there any established URL scheme for browser local storage and IndexedDB?

Tags: javascript, url, browser, local-storage, indexeddb

I'm working on a JavaScript library that can save some artifacts from the browser via multiple saving routes, including browser's local storage and IndexedDB, HTTP requests to servers etc., the disk (in the case of node.js). I feel it would be nice if all these saving routes can all be captured in a unified URL string with varying URL schemes. For HTTP requests and file, it is pretty clear what the URL scheme should be, however, I'm wondering if there are any existing, established URL schemes for local storage and IndexedDB. Please advise.

Comment: Can you explain with example what you are looking for? It is a bit unclear from the description as of now

Answer (score 0):

Blob URLs are living only until document unload event (for example tab close).

For viewing your data table content you can use Application tab (Developer tools).
So you can't do any schema URLs.

You can create a blob URL for each item of any your client-side database item, but this URL will be available until document unload, and you need to create new URLs on each document load

If I correctly understand you.